# Mostrar datos de varias tablas con Sqlite

Tags: java, sqlite

tengo esta tabla Producto con estos atributos, pero el atributo Categoria está relacionado a otra tabla(para registrar un producto se debe registrar el id de la categoría al que pertenece)

```
private int idproducto;
private String desproducto;
private double preproducto;
private int canproducto;
private Categorias categorias;
```

El problema es que para listar no se como hacerlo para mostrar el id de la categoría o el nombre... El cursor solo me acepta getInt, getString mas no para obtener el dato de otra tabla relacionada, ayuden; mi método para listar es el siguiente:

```
public static ArrayList<String> listarP (ConexionSQLiteHelper cnn) throws Exception
    {
        ArrayList<Productos> lst=new ArrayList<Productos>();
        ArrayList<String> listaInformacion=new ArrayList<String>();
        Categorias categorias = new Categorias();
        Productos opr = new Productos();
        String sql="select * from productos";
        Cursor cursor=cnn.ejecutarQuery(sql);
        try{
            if (cursor.moveToFirst())
            {
                do {
                    lst.add(new Productos(cursor.getInt(0), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getDouble(2),cursor.getInt(3),cursor.get(??)));
                }while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }

            for(int i=0;i<lst.size();i++)
            {
                //listaInformacion.add(lst.get(i).getIdcategoria() + " - " + lst.get(i).getDescategoria() );

            }
        }catch(Exception ex){
            throw ex;
        }
        return listaInformacion;
    }
```

En la parte que dice: cursor.get(??) no se que poner para obtener el id o el nombre de la categoría.

Answer (score 0):

No. tu error esta en otro lado.

Las bases de datos son relacionales, eso quiere decir que manejan relaciones (definición muy simplificada).

Si vos necesitas traer los nombres de determinados id (o todos), tenes que hacer una consulta que traiga esas columnas que vos queres.

Por mas que agregues relaciones a tu base de datos, tu programa no las conoce y no las va a conocer. Esas relaciones se llaman reglas de negocios, y pueden existir en la db fisicamente, o ser solamente teoricas y quien las controle sea tu programa.

Por lo tanto, lo que vos tenes que arreglar es la forma de traer los datos. Tenes que Joinear las dos tablas, por los campos por el cual se relacionan, y traer las columnas que queres.

tu query, en esta linea:

```
String sql="select * from productos";
```

deberia ser:

```
String sql="select categorias, desccategoria from productos inner join Categorias on categorias.categorias = productos.categorias";
```

Te recomiendo que leas sobre join en bases de datos.

Comment: Te entiendo, pero como haría para traerlo con el cursor... por qué mi clase tiene Producto tiene un atributo de tipo Categoría (id) y el cursor trabaja con getInt, getString, etc.

Comment: Ese codigo que te puse, genera otro cursor. Y¨con ese cursor nuevo, tenes que armar un objeto de tipo Categoria, lo tenes que armar vos con los datos que traes de la base de datos.